# Is there a cross browser way to put a link to my web app on a user's desktop and/or dock?

Tags: web-applications, desktop

I see Remember the Milk does this with Google Gears.  It "just works" on my computer (Chrome + WinXP).  But I can't remember if I had to install Gears separately at some point.  I don't want to bother my users with having to download something...  And does gears just work across platforms?  eg. Mac with Safari

If not is there another way to do this?  I guess I could just tell them to drag the url wherever they want -- but then I don't get my favicon...  right?

Would appreciate any insight here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a small downloadable application that is simply an icon, and when clicked loads your specific url in the clients default browser.